# Make file for larger directory structure

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

I've got several directories with subdirectories containing c or asm files and I want them all compiled/assembled and then linked. I'm not especially picky where the object files go (e.g. a special bin folder or in the src folder) as long as a make clean removes them all.

The structure would look something like this:

```
/src
    /dir1
        /dir1_1
            +file1_1.s
            +file1_2.s
        +file1.s
    /dir2
        +file2.c
```

I'm sure there's some easy way to create a makefile that compiles all files without me having to specify where it should look (compiling all files in one directory is doable with wildcards, but what then?).

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to compile/assemble/link all `.c` and `.s` files under /src, without specifying where they are?

Comment: Yep that's the plan. Getting all files compiled without explicitly specifying the folder structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your project is small enough, you might get away with using a single hand-crafted makefile instead of a more sophisticated build system: check out the [manual page on transformation functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html#Functions) to see what's possible.

Your example project could be compiled with the following non-recursive makefile:

```
targets = $(patsubst %$(1),%$(2),$(foreach dir,$(3),$(wildcard $(dir)/*$(1))))

asmdirs := src/dir1 src/dir1/dir1_1
cdirs := src/dir2

asmobjects := $(call targets,.s,.o,$(asmdirs))
cobjects := $(call targets,.c,.o,$(cdirs))

.PHONY : all clean

all : $(asmobjects) $(cobjects)

clean :
    rm -f $(asmobjects) $(cobjects)

$(cobjects) : %.o : %.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $<

$(asmobjects) : %.o : %.s
    gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

However, because `make` can access the shell, you could also use standard unix tools like `find` instead of the somewhat limited builtin functions, eg

```
asmsources := $(shell find src -name '*.s')
csources := $(shell find src -name '*.c')

asmobjects := $(asmsources:.s=.o)
cobjects := $(csources:.c=.o)
```

Comment: For my relatively small project (about 200 src files) this seems to be the easiest solution, so for now this should be good enough so that I can worry more about the code. If it gets more complicated I'll can still look into more complex solutions.

Comment: You forgot to pass `$CFLAGS` to gcc.  Make already has implicit rules for building a `.o` from a `.c` or `.s`, are you sure you even need those pattern rules?

Answer (score 6):

Do a Google search for 'recursive make considered harmful'.  You'll find the original article which postulates that the recursive make procedure is a bad way of doing business, and you'll find some links to other places which debate the validity of the proposition.

Basically, there are two ways to do builds in a directory hierarchy (with `make`).

1. Recursive make: each directory contains a makefile which builds in sub-directories and then builds in the current directory.
2. Non-recursive make: the makefile includes all the dependent makefiles, and builds up the complete dependency structure for the entire project and only builds the requisite software.

I work routinely on a product where the main build sequence is driven by a hybrid system that uses a shell script plus one makefile for each directory.  One section of the product is managed by a 'RMCH' makefile; most of it is not.  The build script deals with phases of the build, and sequences the directories, and runs `make` in each directory when it is time to do so.  (The source code is in 20k+ files spread over a multitude of directories - it is a big project/product.)

I've also converted a medium-small project (about 20 directories of relevance, and about 400 source files) to work with RMCH (from a script + makefile-per-directory system).  It was a bit mind-blowing at first, but works pretty neatly now it is done.  Whether I did it correctly is open for debate; it was primarily a learning exercise, though I also did some work modifying the code to work with a modern curses library instead of the archaic BSD library that was used as a part of the code (archaic, as in 1982-vintage - the code was last seriously developed in about 1986) and generally upgrading to modern (standard C) standards.  It was also a chance to work with `git` - so, all in all, quite an extensive learning experience.

If you can wrap your brain around RMCH, it is a good system.  If done correctly, with complete and accurate dependency tracking, it removes the guess-work from the build sequence, and it does run fast.  However, migrating even a medium size project to it is fairly hard work - it would be a daunting task to do it on the main product I work on, though the system might well benefit from it.

An alternative is to look at other alternatives to `make`, such as `cmake`, `rake`, `scons`, `bras`, `imake`, or `ant` or whatever else takes your fancy.  Most of those are easily discoverable via a Google search; the hard one is [`bras`](http://directory.fsf.org/project/bras/), which is based on Tcl (as in Tcl/Tk), but is probably largely dead now.  And `imake` is mentioned more for completeness than as a serious suggestion.  You might also look at the GNU Autotools.  Those do not abandon `make`; they build atop `make`.

Comment: The 'recursive make considered harmful' article had some interesting insights and I'll also look into some of the alternatives. Thanks.